# Shader Multicompile

Tags: msbuild

I've created this Task that enables me to include fxc (HLSL shader compiler) in my build process. Now, the thing with shaders is that quite often you got a single source file and want it to be compiled several times with different flags to produce multiple outputs. I can't just add a new Item referencing the same file multiple times with different Metadata since I want this to integrate into Visual Studio and at least VS yells at me for trying to do so. I'm not an expert when it comes to MSBuild and so I'm really not sure about what would be the best way to do this. Of course one solution would be to just add some Metadata value to each Item that points my fxc Task to some custom multicompile-build-script. But if there's a nice way to solve this purely within MSBuild I would prefer that over a custom built system. I tried having a Target generate multiple items during the build (HLSL are the items that run through fxc):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <HLSL Include="default.hlsl">
      <Multicompile>vs</Multicompile>
    </HLSL>
    <HLSL Include="shadow.hlsl" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <Target Name="ShaderMulticompile" BeforeTargets="HLSL" DependsOnTargets="HLSLSelectedFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <HLSL Include="@(HLSL)" Condition="'%(HLSL.Multicompile)' == 'vs'">
        <TargetFile>$(OutDir)%(Filename).vsh</TargetFile>
        <TargetProfile>vs_4_0</TargetProfile>
        <EntryPoint>VertexShader</EntryPoint>
        <Multicompile />
      </HLSL>
      <HLSL Include="@(HLSL)" Condition="'%(HLSL.Multicompile)' == 'ps'">
        <TargetFile>$(OutDir)%(Filename).psh</TargetFile>
        <TargetProfile>ps_4_0</TargetProfile>
        <EntryPoint>PixelShader</EntryPoint>
        <Multicompile />
      </HLSL>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="RemoveShaderMulticompileSourceItems" AfterTargets="ShaderMulticompile">
    <ItemGroup>
      <HLSL Remove="@(HLSL)" Condition="'%(HLSL.Multicompile)' != ''" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CleanShaderMulticompile" BeforeTargets="HLSLClean" DependsOnTargets="ShaderMulticompile" />
</Project>
```

This basically works but I'd need to have metadata like `<Multicompile>vs;ps</Multicompile>` generate both items and there seems to be no easy way to do the necessary string operations without some hacking. I could also add individual metadata values for each kind of item to generate. But I somehow feel like I'm missing the real solution here so I seek your expert advice ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it now by using an additional Task to Split up the Multicompile Metadata and generate new Items for each element. After that i can run other Targets to generate the final Items like this:

```
<!-- This Task splits up the Multicompile Metadata and spawns new Items based on this info -->
<Target Name="HLSLMulticompile" BeforeTargets="HLSL;HLSLClean" DependsOnTargets="HLSLSelectedFiles">
  <HLSLBuild.Multicompile Inputs="@(HLSL)" Condition="'%(HLSL.Multicompile)' != ''">
    <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="HLSLMulti" />
  </HLSLBuild.Multicompile>
  <ItemGroup>
    <HLSL Remove="@(HLSL)" Condition="'%(HLSL.Multicompile)' != ''" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<!-- These Tasks generate the final Items -->
<Target Name="VertexShader" AfterTargets="HLSLMulticompile">
  <ItemGroup>
    <HLSL Include="@(HLSLMulti)" Condition="'%(HLSLMulti.Multicompile)' == 'vs'">
      <TargetFile>$(OutDir)%(Filename).vsh</TargetFile>
      <EntryPoint>VSMain</EntryPoint>
    </HLSL>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="PixelShader" AfterTargets="HLSLMulticompile">
  <ItemGroup>
    <HLSL Include="@(HLSLMulti)" Condition="'%(HLSLMulti.Multicompile)' == 'ps'">
      <TargetFile>$(OutDir)%(Filename).psh</TargetFile>
      <EntryPoint>PSMain</EntryPoint>
    </HLSL>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

This seems to work quite well. Thank You All :)